# how can I set one column in database when one user sign_out with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I set one column called `if_login` in one table called `users`. When I execute `sign_in` path, I use the method `user_sign_in?` to set the column `if_login` value to 1. And how can I modify the codes in `devise` to set the column `if_login` to 0?

here is when excute 'sign_in' path ,the method will set the user's 'if_login' value=1

```rb
if user_signed_in?
    @user.update(if_login:1)
end
@user.save
```

Comment: You need to provide some code if you cannot explain the problem properly, otherwise people will not be able to help you.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add method in ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # here write your code for the update your if_login
    root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks first.I did in ApplicationController like this : `current_user.update(if_login:0)` .However,there comes an error 'undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass',I      think that when executing the 'after_sign_out_path_for' method,the current_user will be lost,how can I preserve it?